# Exchange 2019: Manage distribution groups without EAC

Tags: exchange-server-2019

we currently create our distribution groups directly via EAC and if a department wants to have a new group they have to contact the IT department for creation.
Now we want some individual employees to be able to create and manage the desired distribution groups themselves. These new groups should then also exist in the global address book, so that the employees can use these distribution groups directly.
Does anyone have a good idea for this?
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a native way of letting users create and manage distribution groups themselves.

If you get IT to create the distribution groups with the particular user as manager (ManagedBy), they will be able to add/remove members. This could ease the burden on IT. Furthermore you could script this, which will make it even easier for IT to manage.

It is a very simple procedure to do through PowerShell via. New-DistributionGroup:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/new-distributiongroup?view=exchange-ps